# The term for the amount of weight that overcomes structural integrity

Tags: phrases

In this context I am referring to the point at which the amount of rainwater building up on a leaf compromises its integrity and causes it to collapse and spill said water.

Comment: "Load limit" is one common term for a structure or machine.  Not sure about a leaf.

Comment: What kind of leaf are you talking about? A plant leaf? Which plant? I ask because plant leaves collapse and spill rainwater *without their overall integrity being compromised*, in most cases.

Comment: @JEL There are some plants whose leaves have evolved to contain some water for *rainy* days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thought was that the water has accumulated to the point of ***critical load***.

***[Critical](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/critical)*** defined as:

> 4. Relating to or denoting a point of transition from one state to another.

Comment: You're welcome!  (p.s. if you're going to stick around here on EL&U, the usual suggestion that you 'accept' the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

[Proof load](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Proof+load) is used in construction and engineering as a term for maximum load.

> the greatest load that can be applied to a piece, as a beam, column,
>   etc., without straining the piece beyond the elastic limit.

Maximum load sounds equally good.

Comment: Mechatronics engineer here, never heard it round these parts... But then only a third of my degree was mechanical. Good to know!

Answer (score 1):

"[Capacity](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/capacity)."

> The maximum amount that something can contain.

Answer (score 1):

That is the very literal example of the idiom [The straw that broke the camel's back](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_that_broke_the_camel%27s_back).